# Applying a style to a DataGridCell based on changed cells in DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, formatting

I'm looking for an easy approach on indicating in a DataGrid if a DataTable has changes which were not updated in the database, yet.

What I would like to do is for example on cells which have pending changes, change the background color to show the user that he has changed the value for this particular cell and this will be updated once the Update command gets called.

I'm not really clear on how to approach this. Might implementing a custom DataView be the best way to go or map everything to custom objects within an ObservableCollection, which would mean doing the mapping and update manually behind the curtain.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using .Net framework 2.0+, I guess you mean `DataGridView` instead of `DataGrid`.
You could change the cell style the `DataGridViewCell` on the [CellValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx). The `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` gives you the `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: It's .NET 4 and WPF's DataGrid

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that tag. Google "wpf cell value changed event" might give you some advice: [PropertyChanged/CollectionChanged of the data](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/cell-value-change-event.aspx) or [TargetUpdated event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/0668f13a-ef48-4a80-a146-cfd46dda632d). From the readings, you need to use an event from your data source instead of the datagrid.